# Get audio channel averagePowerLevel AVFoundation swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to access the audio channel average with `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` and then by setting the `setSampleBufferDelegate`.
However, the delegate is not getting called at all. What I'm I missing?

```
func setUpCaptureSession() {
    
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
    
    // Add inputs
    let camera = bestCamera()
    
    // Video
    guard let captureInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera),
       captureSession.canAddInput(captureInput) else {
            return
    }
    captureSession.addInput(captureInput)
    
    
    if captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(.high) { 
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .high
    }
    
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(cameraOutput){
        captureSession.addOutput(cameraOutput)
    }
    
    // Add outputs
    let microphone = bestAudio()
    
    guard let audioInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone),
        captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput) else {
            return
    }
    
    captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
    self.audioInput = audioInput
    
    audioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    
    guard captureSession.canAddOutput(audioDataOutput) else {
        return
    }
    
    audioDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    captureSession.addOutput(audioDataOutput)
    print("videodataoutput added")
    
    // Recording to disk
    guard captureSession.canAddOutput(fileOutput) else {
        return 
    }
    captureSession.addOutput(fileOutput)
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}
```

> Here I'm calling the delegate:
>
> ```
>   extension CameraController: AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
>
>     
>     func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
>         if output == audioDataOutput {
>            print("AUDIO OUTPUT")
>             DispatchQueue.main.async {
>                 print("DELEGATE")
>     
>                 let channel = connection.audioChannels[1];
>                 let averagePowerLevel = channel.averagePowerLevel
>                 print("AVERAGE POWER: \(averagePowerLevel)")
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Everything else is working but AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate is never called.

Comment: are you calling startRunning() on your captureSession?